# Working sample for MPOAuthConnection for iphone

Tags: iphone, oauth

Has anyone got a working code sample for MPOAuthConnection?

I have checkout source from [code.google.com/p/mpoauthconnection](http://code.google.com/p/mpoauthconnection/), but selecting MPAouthTestApp target gives the following error:

> target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but
>   there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Please help me to solve the error or can anyone provide me with a sample working code for MPOAuthConnection?

Comment: Was there ever an answer to this or did you figure it out? I have the same issue.  I would up vote the question but I don't have enough reputation.

John

Comment: @jmosesman , I switched over to google solution, have some infoon my blog. https://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/linkedin-api-access-using-google-data-api/